# Object did not collide with border

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm stuck on this sphere has a `CircleCollider2D` and rectangle has a `BoxCollider2D` i increase the offset of `BoxCollider`. But why sphere not collide from it's border. Sphere go inside and then collide just like this.
[image]

I want that it's collide when sphere touch it's border.I also check with default radius but the same situation occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trigger**

The scripting system can detect when collisions occur and initiate actions using the OnCollisionEnter function. However, you can also use the physics engine simply to detect when one collider enters the space of another without creating a collision. A collider configured as a Trigger (using the Is Trigger property) does not behave as a solid object and will simply allow other colliders to pass through. When a collider enters its space, a trigger will call the OnTriggerEnter function on the trigger object’s scripts.
[http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html](http://unity3d)

**You need to close isTrigger and use OnCollisionEnter(...).**

For example this is my script of wood(which is below ). A smaller wood will be going down.
[image]

This is the beginning of my game
[image]

If I set isTrigger option true, onCollisionEnter2D function doesn't work. I need isTriggerEnter() method instead. it goes through my wood layer.
[image]

But if I set isTrigger false onCollisionEnter2D will be working. It will stay on my wood layer.
[image]

Comment: can you please  do that with your custom script just for example

Comment: thanks i understand your example.just one thing can you please tell me in simple words difference between `Vector2` and `Vector3` in 2d games and why we use this,`Math.Lerp` ,`Math.Clamp` when i see unity official website as a reference guide i don't understand what they are saying

Comment: Assume that you have borders. You want your game object's x position be between -4 and 4 you use math.clamp. If your game object attempt to move -5 this function will make it's position -4. Lerp is about ratio. Assume again you have a value between 1 - 100. You want to have different values between these numbers. If you set t=7 you will get 70. setting 2 will give you 20. Clamp is limiting something, lerp is getting a value between limits.@ZainKhan

Comment: Vector2 and Vector3 difference for 2d game in simple definition

Comment: In 2D games, Vector3 is not usually used for sprites. Using vector3 in 2d games make your game complex with no profits. But if you have 3d objects and you have 2d camera view you may still need to use Vector3 depends on game. For example if you want to rotate a sphere you may need addTorque(..) function which requires Z axis.